# SPL (Shakespear Programming Language) highlighting for NeoVim

Tags: neovim, treesitter, shakespeare-lang

I'm a bit new to TreeSitter and I have been recently trying to create a syntax highlighting for NeoVim for this esoteric language called [SPL](https://shakespearelang.com/1.0/).

I have tried installing the `nvim` plugin `treesitter-playground` and it works, but not with SPL language. It doesn't even try to analyze it and shows an empty page with `.spl` files only.
[image]

I read a bit online and tried to look for a way to make it work. On the treesitter page I looked for the tutorial on how to do it, but it didn't work. I already have the grammar file ready (in a `.json` format), but it throws me an error.

I am using Fedora38 with the newest version of both `nvim` an its plugins (I don't know how much helpful it can be).

If you want to see how the grammar should be, [here](https://github.com/S-Mancl/shakespeare-syntax-highlight) the link to a gh repo of a person that did it, but for VSCode.